# Method of Frobenius for a matrix differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, frobenius-method

Suppose we have the following matrix differential equation,
$$\textbf{Y}'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\textbf{A}(x)\textbf{Y}(x),$$
where
$$\textbf{Y}(x) = [y_1(x), y_2(x), ..., y_m(x)]^T$$
is a vector and
$$\textbf{A}(x)=[a_{ij}(x)]_{1\le i,j,\le m},$$
is a matrix which is smooth and analytic at $x=0$. Are we able to solve this using the method of Frobenius? Can we generate a series of the form
$$\textbf{Y}(x)=x^\sigma\sum_{n=0}^\infty\textbf{Y}_n x^n,$$
where $\sigma$ is given by some kind of indicial equation (see [Wikiepdia on the Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method))?.
Do you know how to calculate a recurrence relation? I want something similar to that shown in [this document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279994246_Power_series_solution_of_first_order_matrix_differential_equations). They calculate a power series solution which only works if $A(x)/x$ is analytic at $x=0$.

Comment: What are broken-power factors?

Comment: The $x^σ$ in your case. In fact, you get the restrictions $σY_0=A_0Y_0$ as indicial equation, so $(σ,Y_0)$ needs to be an eigen-pair of $A_0$. For general initial conditions you have to represent $Y_0$ in the eigen-basis of $A_0$, getting different powers for the resulting Frobenius series. This should work assuming all eigenvalues are simple.

Comment: Thanks. For the second-order ODE, you can sometimes have solutions proportional to $\ln x$. Can something like that happen here?

Comment: Yes, for eigenvalues with multiplicity, of the irreducible kind. That is, if you get generalized eigenvectors. Note that you can "desingularize" as usual be substituting $x=e^t$ (or $x=x_0e^t$).

Comment: Removed first comment, you had the factor $\frac1x$ from the start, making the system singular in $x=0$. So restricting the values to eigenvectors or eigenspaces will essentially reduce the system to uncoupled scalar Euler-Cauchy equations, in the latter case one may get terms with $\ln x$.